# echo xml in php and can used to decode in php

Tags: php

I have script :

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.example.com';
$post = 'response=xml';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST ,1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
echo $result;
?>
```

but it show like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <interface-response> <test>this is test</test><Done>true</Done> <RequestDateTime>1/16/2016 7:50:01 AM</RequestDateTime> <debug><![CDATA[]]></debug> </interface-response>
```

it's look text and can't used,i want echo it look like [this](http://reference.mapinfo.com/software/spatial_server/english/1_0/onprem/apiguide/API/Web/sample_xml.html)

it look [this](http://prntscr.com/9quvju) but i want to look [this](http://prntscr.com/9quvz5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below line as the first statement in php script. That solves it

```
header('Content-type: application/xml');
```